# How to download files that were created by a slackbot?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I created a bot which collects info from users in a workspace. It stores this info in a csv file on the local server. How do I download said file? I got this bit of code from Stack Overflow, attempted to contact the author but didn't get any response.

```
import requests
url = 'https://slack-files.com/T0JU09BGC-F0UD6SJ21-a762ad74d3'
token = 'xoxp-TOKEN'
requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % token})
```

How do I obtain the URL & token of the file? What is the token? Is it the OAuth token of the bot?

Say I wished to download the file named `stats.csv` from the server that was created by the slackbot and I don't have it's URL, how would I download it?

Comment: `r = requests.get(...)` `f = open(..., 'wb')` `f.write(r.content)` `f.close()`

Comment: requests has also function to download in chains. OR use `urllib.request.urlretrive(url, filename)`

Comment: I really don't understand, could you provide some code example?

Comment: you have code example in first comment. You have to assign `requests.get()` to variable, open file and write `r.content` from your request to file. This way you have all page from your ulr in file. And you can try to cut off interesting part using `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: I don't see on this page link directly to file

Comment: if you want to download `stats.csv` then first you have to find URL for this file. I don't see any method to find it.

Comment: You compromised your Slack token by sharing it on this public post. please disable it and create a new one. ty

Comment: I am not 100% sure if you want to download files from Slack as your code examples suggest or from a web server as you text suggest. I have answered the former below. For the later you want to use a FTP client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not recommend to patch together the URL for downloading the file yourself, because Slack might change it and then your code breaks.

Instead, first get the current URL of the file by calling the API method [`files.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.info) with the file ID. Then use property `url_private` as URL for download. Alternatively you can also call [`files.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.list) to get the list of all files with IDs and their URLs.

To ensure you have access to the file its best to use the token from it's creator, e.g. your slackbot.

I also included the code to save the downloaded data to file and some rudimentary error handling. Note that the token is excepted to be set as environment variable names `SLACK_TOKEN`. This is much safer than putting it directly into the code.

Here is a complete example:

```
import os
import requests

token = os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN']
file_id = "F12345678"

# call file info to get url
url = "https://slack.com/api/files.info"
r = requests.get(url, {"token": token, "file": file_id})
r.raise_for_status
response = r.json()
assert response["ok"]
file_name = response["file"]["name"]
file_url = response["file"]["url_private"]
print("Downloaded " + file_name)

# download file
r = requests.get(file_url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % token})
r.raise_for_status
file_data = r.content   # get binary content

# save file to disk
with open(file_name , 'w+b') as f:
  f.write(bytearray(file_data))
print("Saved " + file_name + " in current folder")
```

Comment: Is there a way to search by file name instead of ID? I don't know what ID the bot saves the files under...

Comment: yes. first call `files.list` to get the list of all files with their ID and names. there you can search for the right file name and pick the URL for download

Comment: btw. you can also directly call most API methods in the browser. e.g. to get the list just add your token to this url and open in browser: `https://api.slack.com/api/files.list?token=TOKEN`