# How to use the permalink_public URL of an uploaded image to include it in a message?

Tags: python, slack-api

I am trying to upload an image to slack and post it in an image block of a slack message to a specific channel.

1. upload an image to Slack.
2. make the image public with [`files.sharedPublicURL`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.sharedPublicURL)
3. check if the url is public: `public_url_shared` being `true`.
4. use the `permalink_public` I receive for the uploaded image for creating the slack message (an image block).

for debugging I am using Slack's Block Kit Builde. I am replacing the URL in the `image_url` example of the [block kit demo](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22image%22%2C%22title%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22plain_text%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Example%20Image%22%2C%22emoji%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22image_url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2Fimg%2Fblocks%2Fbkb_template_images%2Fgoldengate.png%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22Example%20Image%22%7D%5D) with the one I received from slack:

```
https://slack-files.com/T04AG7BVD-FLWHBHY86-1ba8263c00
```

or:

```
https://slack-files.com/T04AG7BVD-FLNJJURL1-7b17f26c80
```

The image should be shown. Instead there is the error in Slack's Block Kit Builder as well as a direct slack-api call: `Downloading image failed.`

If I open the `permalink_public` in an incognito session. I can see the file. so it is public.

Comment: I tried open your image link, but it does not show any image. Are you sure its public? This is what I get: https://i.imgur.com/4aLkP3N.png

Comment: @ErikKalkoken yes, the image is correct. it's my fallback image. quite confusing. here is another one: https://slack-files.com/T04AG7BVD-FLNJJURL1-7b17f26c80 with the same problem.

Comment: and by the way. with your URL https://i.imgur.com/4aLkP3N.png the image is correctly displayed.

Comment: OK, I think the reason for your problem is that `permalink_public` does not give you a direct link to the image file, but links to a website that shows the image.

Comment: I think I figured our how to get the direct link. Will put it in an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason the link for `permalink_public` does not work in your layout block is that it links to a public website showing the image, but is not a direct link to the image file (which is what you need of course).

But you can construct a direct image link from the link to the website.

The website link you get from `permalink_public` has the format:

```
https://slack-files.com/{team_id}-{file_id}-{pub_secret}
```

The direct link to the image has the format:

```
https://files.slack.com/files-pri/{team_id}-{file_id}/{filename}?pub_secret={pub_secret}
```

So you just need to extract the `pub_secret` from `permalink_public` and you should be able to construct the direct link to the image. The other parameters you can get from your file object.

Example for your image:

```
https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T04AG7BVD-FLWHBHY86/no_image_found.png?pub_secret=1ba8263c00
```

Note that this does no appear to be a documented approach, so as all undocumented approaches and hacks its subject to change.

Comment: Response from `files.sharedPublicURL`   has several links to thumbnails of image e.g. `'thumb_1024': 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/{team_id}-{file_id}-123abc/file-name_1024.png'`. They could provide direct link here as well ;-)

Comment: What about the `'is_public'` property? It is still false while `'public_url_shared': True`. Would setting `is_public : True` provide a direct link in response or at least make all the thumb links public?

Comment: All other URLs require you to provide token authorization to retrieve the file. That works great if you access a file from your app, but it won't work for a message, because you can't provide authorization there. Here is an example on how that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57019688/4379151

Comment: The `is_public` property refers to sharing the file in a public channel on Slack, not making a public URL.

Comment: When uploading image files with spaces in the filename string replace with underscore

Comment: The `url_private` property has this entire string already `https://files.slack.com/files-pri/{team_id}-{file_id}/{filename}` so you can simplify your implementation by just extracting the `pub_secret` from `permalink_public` and adding the `?pub_secret={pub_secret}` to `url_private`. A bit odd that 2 years later and this is not supported officially...