# Use a files.upload image as an image in a slack message block

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I want to use a local file (image) in a block.
As far as I know there is no way to use a local image in a message block directly, so I've decided to try to use a files.upload to first upload the image to slack and then use the link to that image in a block.

1. Upload image using files.upload
2. Get link for that image
3. Post a message block with the link to the image.

Problem is no matter what I do, I can't seem to get a valid link that I can then use in the message block. (All I get are "downloading image failed" errors).

I don't want the image to be publicly accessible. I want it to be only accessible to slack users logged into our slack workspace. So I need a link that my slackbot can use but not a public link.

Is there any way to do this?

I've already checked [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253156/how-to-use-the-permalink-public-url-of-an-uploaded-image-to-include-it-in-a-mess) and followed instructions there to try and get a link useable by my bot but I couldn't make it work.

Thank you very much for any help.

Block I'm trying to send:
(for now I'm not dynamically building the link, just trying to do it manually till I get a link that works)

```
webclient.chat_postMessage(
channel=channel_id,
blocks=[
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "TEST TEST TEST"
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "image",
            "image_url": "https://slack-files.com/files-pri/T024G****-FU85H****/file?pub_secret=e54507****",
            "alt_text": "User's picture"
        }
    }
]
```

Files.upload response:

```
{'text': '', 'files': [{'id': 'FU85H****', 'created': 158279****, 'timestamp': 158279****, 'name': 'file', 'title': "User's image:", 'mimetype': 'image/png', 'filetype': 'png', 'pretty_type': 'PNG', 'user': 'UPTM1****', 'editable': False, 'size': 114035, 'mode': 'hosted', 'is_external': False, 'external_type': '', 'is_public': False, 'public_url_shared': False, 'display_as_bot': False, 'username': '', 'url_private': 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T024G****-FU85H****/file', 'url_private_download': 'https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T024G****-FU85H****/download/file', 'thumb_64': 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T024G****-FU85H****-9513e3****/file_64.png', 'thumb_80': 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T024G****-FU85H****-9513e3****/file_80.png', 'thumb_360': 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T024G****-FU85H****-9513e3****/file_360.png', 'thumb_360_w': 291, 'thumb_360_h': 256, 'thumb_160': 'https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T024G****-FU85H****-9513e3****/file_160.png', 'image_exif_rotation': 1, 'original_w': 291, 'original_h': 256, 'thumb_tiny': 'AwAqADBYCFJ3EgEY4qx5kRB+8OAOnpSC3T1NKYEA6mgBGnhQ7mYjknp60xZYHA2OSVHHHSq5RWnfdyFOBmlkiVcFTgjnilcdie4lWQDGeKr7gDVw2yHuaYbRPVqegiXdQW4qIvUEl0icZyfQUAOYDc2R3zSoodgOvaoomaXLnjngelSOXjQupwRzUlrYvGmmq****/DHY3v0qbNUQZ11KVUKDyetVKmuv9b+FQUAWrST5yD3qS8k+UKD15qrF98fUf****/1x+goHfQhJycmrlnOeIzz6V****/160CP/9k=', 'permalink': 'https://gaia.slack.com/files/UPTM1****/FU85H****/file', 'permalink_public': 'https://slack-files.com/T024G****-FU85H****-e54507****', 'is_starred': False, 'has_rich_preview': False}], 'upload': True, 'user': 'UPTM1****', 'display_as_bot': False, 'team': 'T024G****', 'source_team': 'T024G****', 'user_team': 'T024G****', 'channel': 'DUFV5****', 'event_ts': '158279****.002500', 'ts': '158279****.002500'}
```

Comment: Share your code

Comment: The procedure in the related question works. Most likely there is a bug in your code. Would be great if you could add it to the question, so people can help you find it.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Updated OP with my code and files.upload response.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I didn't think the python tag made sense here, as the question is language-agnostic. As  far as I can tell, it is only related to the slackapi aspect.

Comment: I disagree. Your problem occurs with code written in Python, so it makes sense to tag it accordingly. Even if it should be API related (what we don't know at the moment). It also helps with syntax formatting.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I see. Well I guess if that is how tags work on SO, I'm still new sorry ^^' Thanks for the tip, if you need any additional information, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: OK, so you say you don't want to make the image URL public, but blocks will only work with public URLs. The linked example also includes making the URL public (by calling `files.sharedPublicURL`). Did you try that?

Comment: If you can not use public image URLs the only alternative is to share the image directly in the channel with file_upload, e..g after your message. You can also include a message with that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186399/how-to-create-a-slack-message-containing-an-uploaded-image/58189401#58189401 for details.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I want it to be publicly accessible to all those in the slack workspace (my bot included) but not outside of that. Is that not possible?
(and no I didn't know I had to use a separate method to make the link accessible)
And concerning your second message: Yes that is what I am doing right now, but that is such a dirty solution, I really wanted to use blocks so that the image could be properly formatted with the text...

Comment: No, as I said you can only use real public URLs in blocks. But there is an alternative, please check the answer I linked in my last comment.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I see, but your link doesn't fit my constraints, so I guess what I want isn't feasible at this point in time. thanks for your time trying to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP wants to create message block with a private image URL. That is not possible.

Image URLs in messages blocks (and attachments) need to be public.

An alternative is to directly share an uploaded image file in a channel and include a message.

Details on how to include images in message are described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186399/how-to-create-a-slack-message-containing-an-uploaded-image/58189401#58189401).